# How to assign hostname to the web server?

Tags: webserver, ip-address, lighttpd, hostname

I am using lighttpd as my webserver.

Currently I am accessing it using the IP address as :

```
http://192.168.0.1
```

I want to access it as

```
http://myhostname.com
```

I would be using it in the local network only, and not the internet.

I don't know how to do this. I googled, but don't know the exact keywords to use.

Comment: Belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the following line to the file `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.0.1              myhostname.com
```

For instance, using the following command:

```
$ sudo echo -e '192.168.0.1\tmyhostname.com' >> /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add a rule in your hosts file: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

add a rule like

```
192.168.0.1     myhostname.com
```

In windows you can't do this with wildcards so for all subdomains you need to add a rule

Comment: I am using linux and the web server is lighttpd 1.4.28.. Can you tell me in this context please?

Comment: In linux the file can be found as /etc/hosts like told by Yasir Arsanukaev

Answer (score 1):

[Find your hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system) on your local machine, and then add the following line to it:

```
192.168.0.1       www.somedomain.com
```